# Javascript characters or numbers count

Tags: javascript, html

How can we count the number of characters entered in the textbox in javascript?
Let me know what I missed.

```js
function count1() {
  var len = Number(document.getElementById("num1").value);
  var n = len.length;
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = n;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    Enter Num: <input id="num1">
    <button onclick="count1()">Try it</button>
    <input id="demo1">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you convert the value to a number? The len variable should be the content (as string) and you can find the length of that string.

Comment: You're outputing your results in an input field. Change your .innerHTML to .value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to get [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) of the first input's [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties) and set it to the second input's [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties)
 (instead of using [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)):

```js
function count1() {
  var len = document.getElementById('num1').value.length;
  document.getElementById("demo1").value = len;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    Enter Num: <input id="num1">
    <button onclick="count1()">Try it</button>
    <input id="demo1">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @SReddy I'm glad to help, you can accept my answer then.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need of `Number` & replace `innerHTML` with `value` which is appropriate attribute for input.The primary objective of `Number` is to convert an argument to a number.For example `"1"` which is a string will be converted to `1` but it will not able to convert alphabets or characters to number. In your case if you use number it will return a `NaN`

```js
function count1() {
  var len = (document.getElementById("num1").value).length;
  document.getElementById("demo1").value = len;
}
```

```html
Enter Num: <input id="num1">
<button onclick="count1()">Try it</button>
<input id="demo1">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could directly take the string and the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) property for assigning to the value property of the text field.

```js
function count1() {
    document.getElementById("demo1").value = document.getElementById("num1").value.length;
}
```

```html
Enter Num: <input id="num1">
<button onclick="count1()">Try it</button>
<input id="demo1">
```

Answer (score 0):

> Number() function is unusable!
>   and use `value` instead of `innerHTML` to change the **input** element text

```js
function count1() {
  var len = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  var n = len.length;
  document.getElementById("demo1").value = n.toString();
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Enter Num: <input id="num1">
<button onclick="count1()">Try it</button>
  <input id="demo1">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is the `toString()` in `n.toString()` necessary?

Comment: @torazaburo it's not, the interpreter transforms it to string! just a habit to convert the numbers to string :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in javascript that updates the count for a text input as you type:

```js
document.querySelector('input[name="firstname"]').oninput=updateCount;
function updateCount(event) {
    var countSpan = document.querySelector('span#count');
    countSpan.textContent = event.target.value.length;
}
```

```html
<label for="firstname">First Name</label>
<input name="firstname" type="text"/>
<div>
  Your first name has <span id="count">0</span> letters.
</div>
```